# GestureRecogniser doesn't respond

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Beginner here- the below code works fine in TouchesBegan function. But doesn't work with GestureRecongnizer (swipe or tap). It seems like the gesture recognizer doesn't respond at all.

I'm working on swift 2 and xcode 7.3

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{ ...
let SwipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.Dragged(_:)))
   SwipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
    self.egg.addGestureRecognizer(SwipeUp)
 }
  func Dragged(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        let eggFrame = self.egg.frame
        eggFrame.origin.y -= 700
        self.egg.frame = eggFrame
        }, completion: { finished in print("done!") } 
}
```

Comment: How is this even compiling? Swift shouldn't allow you to mutate a struct that has been declared let. ```let eggFrame = self.egg.frame;
        eggFrame.origin.y -= 700```

Comment: But it does. I don't know why.

Comment: You code worked fine for me when I changed `let` to `var`

Comment: Let me check that. Thank you for catching the glich though

Comment: I tried doing that. Still not working.

Comment: I know. Is this the code as it is written in your project or some pseudocode that you've made up for the sake of this question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a strong reference to the UIGestureRecognizer.

```
var swipeUp: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.Dragged(_:)))
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
    self.egg.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
}

func Dragged(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        let eggFrame = self.egg.frame
        eggFrame.origin.y -= 700
        self.egg.frame = eggFrame
    }, completion: { finished in print("done!") } 
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. You do not need to keep strong reference to gesture recognizer. When you add it to the view, that keeps a strong reference for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` only recognizes swipe gestures on the element you attached it to (the egg). If you do a rapid swipe up in the egg view it should recognize the swipe.

If you want to add Drag or Tap gesture recognizers, you have to add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the egg.

Are you sure that the Dragged method is not being called?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Because it doesn't even print "done!" on the output console. It should if the function was being called.